# SSIS import of Excel file doesn'T include all coloumns

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I'm trying to import an Excel file with 8 columns: one date-type the other seven varchars, to SQL Server. When I try to map the columns in Visual Studio there is one column missing from the Excel sheet.

How can I fix it?

By the way the last column is the one that's missing and the 7th column is a large column (width = 254,29). When I change the column width manually the 8th column appears. But it wasn't the Intention to Change the layout of the Excel sheet every time.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, Excel 2013 and SQL- Server 2014.

Now the Task is working on my local machine but if I try to deploy it on the Server it fails. On the Server the last column couldn't be mapped because it is missing in the Excel sheet. But if I open the Excel sheet on the Server it is the newest Version.

Comment: Was the column added to the file after the mapping ?

Comment: The column isn't even shown for mapping. I got 8 columns as mentioned in my Excel sheet but in the mapping table are only 7 shown

Comment: Sorry,  I thought it could be a first mapping without the last column in the excel file, then added in the excel file the column and use the same mapping

Comment: There was no previous mapping and the table is created shortly before I tryed to import the data. But the Problem musst be caused by column width.